# Trouble with servlet url-pattern matching with wildcards

Tags: java, spring, servlets

I am having difficulty getting requests mapped to the correct servlet when the servlet-mapping url-pattern uses a wildcard. I want all requests that begin with "/profile-api" to be mapped to a new REST service I'll be writing soon.

From web.xml:

```
<!-- default servlet -->
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>professional</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<!-- profile api -->
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>profile-api</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/profile-api/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Pseudo-code from the controller that allows a third-party system to update a user's "email communication opt-in status" (OptinResponse is a domain class that will ultimately be transformed to JSON and returned to caller):

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/profile-api")
public class ProfileAPIController {
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value="/setoptin/{userID}")
    public @ResponseBody OptinResponse setOptinStatus(@PathVariable String userID) {
        return new OptinResponse("200", "Successfully set optin status for user: " + userID);
    }
}
```

I would expect a request to "{localhost}/profile-api/setoptin/12345" to be correctly routed to the ProfileAPIController, but it is not.

Changing the servlet-mapping url-pattern to be more specific but still generic also fails:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>profile-api</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/profile-api/setoptin/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

The ONLY way I have been able to get my request routed as intended is to include the full, exact path:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>profile-api</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/profile-api/setoptin/12345</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Obviously, that's unacceptable, as the user id must be variable.

In all cases, the request is instead mapped to the default "professional" servlet. I have tried reordering the servlet-mapping nodes to no avail. I have "alwaysUseFullPath" set to "true" in the AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter bean in the servlet config (but have tried it as "false", too). I feel as though I'm overlooking something simple, but can't see the forest for the trees.

Comment: Try removing `@RequestMapping` annotation, there may be some ambiguity.

Comment: Wow, that was really fast! That solved the problem and it's now working as expected. Thank you!

Comment: Nice that you have set the `alwaysUseFullPath` on the `AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter`, however that is not the one that is being used. The `RequestMethodHandlerMapping` should be used instead. (Assuming that you have `<mvc:annotation-driven />` or `@EnableWebMvc`. To fix, create a `BeanPostProcessor` that sets the desired property on the correct instance (adding a bean of that type will not help!). But do you really need 2 different servlets? Why not simply handle them in a single on?